# How to Find $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_8 × \mathbb Z_8)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find a group that is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z_8 × \mathbb Z_8)$.

In case there's a product of more than two groups, how could I find its automorphic object? Is there any typical algorithm to find one?

Answer (score 2):

I presume $Z8=\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$. In this case the automorphism group of
$\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$ is $\text{GL}_2(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)$
the group of two by two invertible matrices over $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$.
In general the automorphism group of a direct product of
$n$ copies of $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z$ is $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)$.

In general, there won't always be a simple description
of the automorphism group of a direct product of groups.

Comment: how to prove : in general, the automorphism group of a direct product of n copies of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is $GL_n(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$

Comment: there's a typo of $n$ as $m$

Comment: I'd say $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$ is merely another name for $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z \times \cdots \times \mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z)$, so this seems like a non-answer to me.

Comment: @Christoph The group $\text{GL}_n(\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z)$ is a perfect answer for an automorphism group, isn't it?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sure $G$ is a valid answer for "find a group isomorphic to $G$", i.e. the phrasing of the question allows for this trivial answer.

Comment: @Christoph This is not a trivial answer. The automorphism group is just trivially one of the most famous groups, the linear group over the ring $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. So the question is trivial, not the answer.